# Is it possible to use Windows Authentication on RavenDB when installed as a Windows Service?

Tags: iis, ravendb, windows-authentication

Is it possible to use Windows Authentication on RavenDB when installed as a Windows Service? Or do we need to host it within IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.
You don't need any special configuration to do so, any Windows Service installation will support Windows Auth.